# Check both JCheckBox and JButton in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

So I finished working on an interface for my program, but now I need to actually make my program do stuff. I have been using Java for a while now, but some things (like this one) are still very new to me

I have searched extensively, on here, on other sites, and on the Oracle website. But the closest I could find to what I need, was this exact question, only for JavaScript.

What I have is a button, and 17 checkboxes.

What I need to do (for every single checkbox), is check if the checkbox is checked, and if it is, also check if the button is clicked (it's not a toggle button btw). And then run a code.

Now for the sake of the code having as few lines as possible, I was hoping to do something like making the main code call upon another .class file, which would be the code that executes if both the button and checkbox return true. Instead of pasting the code for every single checkbox boolean.

So simply put, this is what I need:

```
If (JCheckBox is checked) {
    If (JButton is pressed) {
       Call other .class file
  }
}

else {

}
```

Now this would have to go under every single checkbox, and I would need to check for the button every single time. So alternatively, I could just put all the code for the booleans, under the JButton's code, and save a lot of lines. But I don't know if it's possible to check for one object, in another object's code block.

Here is a snippet of the code for the button and one of the checkboxes.

```
//"Clean" button
JButton btnClean = new JButton("Clean");
    btnClean.setBounds(244, 149, 100, 50);
    btnClean.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));            
    panel_Clean.setLayout(null);
    panel_Clean.add(btnClean);

//Checkbox "Temporary Files" (Registry)
JCheckBox chckbxTemporaryFilesRegistry = new JCheckBox("Temporary Files");
chckbxTemporaryFilesRegistry.setBounds(12, 80, 162, 15);
panel_Destination.add(chckbxTemporaryFilesRegistry);
```

So from the pseudo-code above this snippet, you can see that I want to put a set of "if" statements, either in the checkbox, or the button code block. Depending on which one would be more efficient, and then call upon another class file that is located in the same folder as the main class file (the one that makes the interface).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ActionListener. This listener runs some code when the button is prssed.
First make sure you implement the ActionListener

```
implements ActionListener
```

Then add the button to the Action Listener.

```
btnClean.addActionListener(this);
```

Now, you can edit your ActionPerfomed method

```
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae){
    if(chckbxTemporaryFilesRegistry.isSelected()){
      //dosomething
    }

}
```

I hope that solves you problem. Have a nice day.

Comment: Your answer helped a lot, but I'm unsure as to where I would put the

Comment: You could add implements ActionListener to your class declaration :)

Comment: Sorry, accidentally hit enter.

... "implements ActionListener" and the method at the bottom of your answer.

I didn't mention this, but my code has a lot of methods at the top, and either I don't know if I'm putting this one in the right place, or I think I am, but it's giving me errors that I don't understand.

Comment: put implements ActionListener at the end of your class "name". This is one of the first lines.

Comment: Your ide should throw an error and give you a solution to add a method.

Comment: I used the quick fix the ide gave me to make the method, and I pasted in your if statement, but now I'm getting the following error.

"chckbxTemporarayFilesRegistry cannot be resolved"

Comment: you have to make chckbxTemporarayFilesRegistry global.

Comment: JCheckBox chckbxTemporaryFilesRegistry = new JCheckBox("Temporary Files"); remove the JCkeckBox in the beginning. And then write below your class declaration JCheckBox chckbxTemporaryFilesRegistry;

Comment: The reason for this is, that your CheckBox reference is a locale reference and only acessable in the method.

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! ;D
I could literally jump across the globe and hug you right now! Thank you so much!

Also, could you please explain what that does exactly? I mean, what does it mean by making the checkbox global?

Comment: I already tried to explain this above your last comment. Its about the range of validity. If you declare a var in a method you can only access the var within the method.

Comment: Okay thank you for the clarification. :)
Also, I don't like being that guy... But you misspelled "Temporary". ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `chckbx.isSelected()` for the checkbox, but for the button you will have to use an `EventListener` such as an [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) or a [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html)